# EDGE Browser Link Color change to faded color after Hover

Tags: html, hyperlink, microsoft-edge

[sample screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG5xK.jpg)

In my project when I hover over a link item, the text color of the link changes to a faded color only **after HOVER HAPPENS**. This only happens whilst using EDGE browser please help..

Comment: Finally I found a solution i updated edge browser via windows update problem solved

Answer (score 0):

To turn off the gray shading when links are tapped add a meta tag to the head section:

`<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />`

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182645(v=vs.85).aspx?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5000527) for more details.

Comment: Finally I found a solution i updated edge browser via windows update problem solved